# Will the basis of Nul(A) and Col(A) be linearly independent in a nxn matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Will the vector set containing both the basis of Nul(A) and the basis of Col(A)  be linearly independent for a nxn matrix?

If not, in which cases are they?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: basis by definition is linearly independent

Comment: yes, but if you put the vectors of the basis of Nul(A) together with Col(B), will the set of vectors still be linearly independent? I know that sum of the dimensions equals n.

Comment: The question is unclear as it is. But if it's about linear independency of the joint system, which consists of both bases, then one of the answers is: iff $\operatorname{\mathrm{Nul}}A=\operatorname{\mathrm{Nul}}A^2$.

Comment: Or, perhaps simpler to check: Iff $A$ and $A^2$ have the same rank.

Answer (score 1):

In general the question makes no sense since the null space is a subspace of the domain and the column space is a subspace of the codomain.

Even when you consider them to be subspaces of the same space (essentially by using the standard coordinate system), the answer is "no". For the matrix
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0  & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
the vector $(1,0)$ spans both the kernel and the image.

(This is an example satisfying 
$$
\ker A = \ker A^2
$$
as in the comment from @SergeyGolovan .)

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the first paragraph here. Since the question was specifically about an $n\times n$ _matrix_ rather than an abstract linear transformation, the domain and codomain are both implicitly $\mathbb R^n$ (or in general $F^n$). One doesn't need to "force them" to be the same.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Fair enough. I was trying to reinforce the generality of the rank-nullity theorem, which the OP may not grasp. I'll edit to change "force" to "consider".